# How to make an "Add to favourites" and show in favourite list in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, addition

I am building a table view app. There are images on the cells. My question is, how to add the images to the 'favorite"? In the 'favorite' page, I want to see the images on the cell, which is in other view controller. How to make the 'Add to Favorite' button and how the datas are added to the favorite page? Anyone please help me? I will be so grateful if anyone help me with that. I am using Swift 4 and I am new in Swift.

Comment: The best way to do this is to use CoreData. You create a button, and every time you press the button it is saved in a CoreData model or deleted. In the other ViewController you call up the CoreData model and add it to the tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    @IBAction func isFavoriteButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)
        guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition) else { return }
        guard let shoe_ID = sneakerModel[indexPath.row].ID else { return }
        
        let checkFavorite = CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.loadIsFavorite(shoe_ID: shoe_ID)
        
        if checkFavorite == true {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star"), for: .normal)
            CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.updateIsFavorite(shoe_ID: shoe_ID, isFavorite: false)
        } else if checkFavorite == false {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star.fill"), for: .normal)
            CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.updateIsFavorite(shoe_ID: shoe_ID, isFavorite: true)
        }
    }
}
```

CoreData stuff:

```
func loadIsFavorite(shoe_ID: String) -> Bool{
    
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Project> = NSFetchRequest< Project >(entityName: "Project")
    var favorite = Bool()
    
    do {
        let sneaksObject = try context.fetch(request)
        
        
        for i in 0..<sneaksObject.count {
            if shoe_ID == sneaksObject[i].shoe_ID {
                favorite = sneaksObject[i].isFavorite
            }
        }
        
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    return favorite
}

func updateIsFavorite(shoe_ID: String, isFavorite: Bool) {
    
    let request: NSFetchRequest< Project > = NSFetchRequest< Project >(entityName: "Project")
    do {
        let sneaksObject = try context.fetch(request)
        
        for i in 0..<sneaksObject.count {
            if shoe_ID == sneaksObject[i].shoe_ID {
                sneaksObject[i].setValue(isFavorite, forKey: "isFavorite")
                saveContext()
            }
        }
        saveContext()
        
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps to achieve this.

Step 1 : Create a 'CoreData' model in your project.

Step 2 : Save the image details in `CoreData`

Step 3 : Fetch from `CoreData` and show it in another view controller

Learn more about [CoreData](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7569-getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial)